# Excel 2011 crashes when printing certain worksheets

Tags: ms-office

Excel 2011 (for Mac) consistently crashes on certain `.xlsx` files, at the moment I want to print it (either directly to the printer or to PDF). With Excel 2016 (both Windows and Mac), it works fine.

The only thing I know, the Excel is created by a colleague who uses Excel for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The Excel-worksheet probably contains an embedded OLE object. Within Excel you can check this by right clicking each "image". When the context-menu's last option is `Format object`, you found it.

To fix it, choose the option `Save as image` and choose a location and name. Then delete the object, and insert the previously saved image.

---

There is also **another way to check for embedded objects**. An `.xlsx` file is actually also a `.zip` file. You can rename the extension so you can unzip it (or use `unzip filename.xlsx -d directory_to_unzip_to` on the command line).

When the newly created folder contains a folder `xl/embeddings`, and this folder contains at least one file, the excel contains an embedded object.